# Is it possible to use user defined fuctions when expanding macro?

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme, define-syntax

From chicken scheme manual:

> define-syntax evaluates the procedure in a distinct expansion environment (initially having access to the exported identifiers of the scheme module)

Is it possible to inject the *user-function* to the expansion environment?

```
(define-syntax my-macro
  (er-macro-transformer
   (lambda (exp rename compare)
     (user-function exp)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use `begin-for-syntax` or `require-extension-for-syntax` (the last one also known as `use-for-syntax`.